# Cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, visual-studio-2012

```
class EventDataValue {
public:
    enum Types {
        NONE,
        INT,
        STRING,
        DOUBLE,
        ULONG
    };

    EventDataValue() { this->Type = NONE; }
    EventDataValue( const EventDataValue &s ) { 
        this->Type = s.Type;

        if (this->Type == INT) 
            this->i = s.i;
        else if (this->Type == STRING)
            this->s = s.s;
        else if (this->Type == DOUBLE)
            this->d = s.d;
        else if (this->Type == ULONG)
            this->ul = s.ul;
    }

    EventDataValue& operator=( const EventDataValue &s ) { 
        this->Type = s.Type;

        if (this->Type == INT) 
            this->i = s.i;
        else if (this->Type == STRING)
            this->s = s.s;
        else if (this->Type == DOUBLE)
            this->d = s.d;
        else if (this->Type == ULONG)
            this->ul = s.ul;

        return *this; 
    }


    EventDataValue(int value) {
        this->Type = INT;
        this->i = value;
    }

    EventDataValue(CString &value) {
        this->Type = STRING;
        this->s = value;
    }

    EventDataValue(LPCTSTR value) {
        this->Type = STRING;
        this->s = CString(value);
    }

    EventDataValue(double value) {
        this->Type = DOUBLE;
        this->d = value;
    }

    EventDataValue(unsigned long value) {
        this->Type = ULONG;
        this->ul = value;
    }

    ~EventDataValue() { }

    operator int(void) const {
        return this->i;
    }

    operator CString(void) const {
        return this->s;
    }

    operator double(void) const {
        return this->d;
    }

    operator unsigned long(void) const {
        return this->ul;
    }


    Types Type;
    int i;
    CString s;
    double d;
    unsigned long ul;
};

class EventData {
public:
    EventData(CString strEventCode, CString &strSessionId, int nFlowId = 0) {
        this->Add(CString(_T("tp")), strEventCode);
        this->Add(CString(_T("ss")), strSessionId);
        this->Add(CString(_T("ts")), (int)std::time(0));

        if (nFlowId != 0)
            this->Add(CString(_T("fl")), nFlowId);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Add(CString name, T value) {
        EventDataValue event_value(value);

        if (cMap.Lookup(name, NULL) == TRUE)
            return;

        cMap[name] = value;
    }

    CMap<CString, CString, EventDataValue, EventDataValue> cMap;
};

class Events {
public:
    Events() { }
    ~Events() { }

    void Add(EventData ev) {
        this->aEvents.Add(ev);
    }

    CStringW Serialize() {
        CStringW strOutput;
        INT_PTR i, j;

        if (_tcscmp(API_FORMAT, FORMAT_JSON) == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i != this->aEvents.GetCount(); i++) {
                EventData ev = this->aEvents[i];

                strOutput += L"{";

                j = 0;

                POSITION pos = ev.cMap.GetStartPosition();

                while (pos != NULL) {
                    CString key;
                    EventDataValue value;

                    ev.cMap.GetNextAssoc( pos, key, value );

                    strOutput += StringFormat(_T("\"%s\": "), key.GetString());

                    if (value.Type == EventDataValue::STRING) {
                        CString str = value;
                        strOutput += Enquoute(str);
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::INT) {
                        int n = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%d"), n);
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::DOUBLE) {
                        double d = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%d"), static_cast<int>(d));
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::ULONG) {
                        ULONG ul = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%u"), ul);
                    }

                    if (j++ < ev.cMap.GetCount() - 1)
                        strOutput += _T(",");
                }

                strOutput += _T("}");
            }
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i != this->aEvents.GetCount(); i++) {
                EventData ev = this->aEvents[i];

                strOutput += _T("<Event>");

                j = 0;

                POSITION pos = ev.cMap.GetStartPosition();

                while (pos != NULL) {
                    CString key;
                    EventDataValue value;

                    ev.cMap.GetNextAssoc( pos, key, value );

                    strOutput += StringFormat(_T("<%s>"), key.GetString());

                    if (value.Type == EventDataValue::STRING) {
                        CString str = value;
                        strOutput += str;
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::INT) {
                        int n = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%d"), n);
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::DOUBLE) {
                        double d = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%d"), static_cast<int>(d));
                    } else if (value.Type == EventDataValue::ULONG) {
                        ULONG ul = value;
                        strOutput += StringFormat(_T("%u"), ul);
                    }

                    strOutput += StringFormat(_T("</%s>"), key.GetString());
                }

                strOutput += _T("</Event>");
            }

        }

        return strOutput;
    }

    CArray<EventData> aEvents;
};
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting the following error when I try to compile this?

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h(1329): error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(559) : see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(534) : see declaration of 'CObject'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CMap<KEY,ARG_KEY,VALUE,ARG_VALUE>::CMap(const CMap<KEY,ARG_KEY,VALUE,ARG_VALUE> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              KEY=CString,
1>              ARG_KEY=CString,
1>              VALUE=EventDataValue,
1>              ARG_VALUE=EventDataValue
1>          ]
```

Comment: `CObject` is not copyable, which means you need to pass and return it by reference only, never by value. And it means that you can't copy objects derived from, or objects that contain objects derived from, `CObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Add(EventData ev) {
    this->aEvents.Add(ev);
}
```

This *must* be `Add(EventData& ev)`. Your `EventData` class has no non-default copy constructor or copy assignment operator and has a member (`CMap`) that is non-copyable. This makes `EventData` non-copyable. So you can't pass it by value because that would have to make a copy, which you can't do since the class is non-copyable.

Answer (score 2):

`CMap` has default copy-ctor. Since `CMap` is derived from `CObject` and `CObject`'s copy c-tor is private you get an error.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `CMap` and `CArray`, I used `std::map` and `std::vector` since `CString` isn't compatible with `CMap` and `CArray`.

Comment: Untrue. I used it extensively in some applications. Take real-world applications' examples from my code: `CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, CMappedPoints*, CMappedPoints*&> MappedPoints` and `CArray<CString> Tags`.