# Unable to return CMap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Using Visual Studio 2012, the following compiles:

```
void Stuff()
{
  CMap <int, int, int, int > myMap;
}
```

But when I try to return such a CMap, like this:

```
CMap<int, int, int, int> GetEncodingMap()
{
  CMap <int, int, int, int> encodingMap;
  return encodingMap;
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(559) : see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(534) : see declaration of 'CObject'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CMap<KEY,ARG_KEY,VALUE,ARG_VALUE>::CMap(const CMap<KEY,ARG_KEY,VALUE,ARG_VALUE> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              KEY=int,
1>              ARG_KEY=int,
1>              VALUE=int,
1>              ARG_VALUE=int
1>          ]
```

This seems to always be the case, no matter what types I use in the CMap.

Could somebody help me understand what his happening?  Is it ever possible to return a CMap from a function?

Comment: That can't be the complete error message. Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018772/cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-cobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMap` is a non-copyable object, as it inherits from `CObject` which has a private copy constructor. If you want to make it copyable, you will need to inherit from CMap and provide your own, although I'm not sure how viable that is.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a convoluted way of MFC trying to prevent you from copying CMap object. You can't copy a CMap object.

Answer (score 0):

GetEncodingMap() method doesn't create an object, just declaring and returning. Try creating before returning.